# SharePoint & Visual Studio 2010 - Can't create a SharePoint project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently in trouble setting up a SharePoint 2010 project.

Today, I installed VS2010 on our new SP 2010 test-server with my domain account, which was prompted with administrator rights on the Server and SharePoint before.

But now I'm failing to create a SharePoint project in Visual Studio. The SharePoint Customization Wizard tells me following:

> Cannont connect to the SharePoint site: http://myserver/blah.
>   Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user as the necessary permissions to access the site.

As I'm 'quite' sure, that SharePoint is running on the locale system and I'm having no problems browsing SharePoint with my account, I'm wondering what is preventing me to create the project.

Somewhere else I've read that the user, which is running VS2010, needs db_owner rights to the config and admin tables of SP2010, which I've done, unfortunately this didn't affect anything.

Has anybody encountered this problem before? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you run VS with admin rights? Another thing that pops up, is using x64 mode.

Comment: Yes, I started VS with admin rights. Otherwise it would prompt the message to do so, on creating the project. What about the x64 mode? Windows Server 2008 and SharePoint are both x64 versions, VS only 32, as their exists only a 32 bit one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! After studying the log files of SharePoint, I've found an error saying, that the database "wss_content_some_fancy_guid" couldn't be opened. After granting rights to it, it worked.